Aggregate function with two polygon layers resluts in incorrect attributes when using Filter = intersects
I have 2 polygon layers (Property Boundary, Land Cover) and what I am trying to do is have it so that when I add a new polygon feature in Land Cover, it inherits the attribute information from my Property Boundary layer.
I am able to get it to work great using the following code but only if there isn't an adjacent Property Boundary feature AND if the new land cover polygon doesn't share a boundary with the Property Boundary feature. If there is an adjacent property and I draw a new Land Cover polygon, along that boundary, it will inherit the attributes of the neighbouring polygon and not the polygon where I actually draw the polygon.
The code I am using is (Verksamhetsområde is my Property Boundary):
aggregate(
    layer:='Verksamhetsområde',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="namn",
    filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )

Here is an example of where the code is correctly pulling the attribute information (red triangle to left, doesn't have any shared boundaries).

But when I add a boundary, here is the error and it pulls the information from the neighboring boundary instead of where it is "inside."

I tried to use contains or within instead of intersects but that returns NULL when the polygon I draw shares a boundary with my Property Boundary layer.
aggregate(
    layer:='Verksamhetsområde',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="namn",
    filter:=contains($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )

I also thought that I could try to use centroid with contains or within but that didn't work either as it always returned NULL for the field when I tried to draw a new polygon.

Does anyone know why QGIS is doing this and/or have any suggestions?

You can use intersects with point_on_surface to intersect the point and the other layers polygon:
aggregate( layer:='Verksamhetsområde', aggregate:='max', expression:="namn", filter:=intersects($geometry, point_on_surface(geometry(@parent))))


Thank you so much!! I had incorrectly used the point_on_surface as I put that on the $geometry thinking it was the newly drawn geometry.

Nice! I also tried that first :)
